# How to Measure foreign Aid dependency

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, development-economics

I am writing a paper regarding foreign aid dependency, and I would like to classify countries as being aid dependent or independent. Is there any criteria in the literature that can be used to distinguish if a country is aid dependent or not. e.g. setting a condition like if foreign aid as a percentage of GDP is bigger than a certain threshold and the average economic growth during the last 5 years is less than certain percent the country is aid dependent.